# Locale date format in PHP5

Tags: php, date, format, locale

my site changes its locale dependent upon either user settings or browser settings (where the user hasn't set their preference). I am using amline charts, the stock chart specifically, which requires the date format in 'MM/DD/YYYY' or 'DD-MM-YYYY', I guess so the chart knows how to understand the dates. There are many ways to format a date dependent upon the computer locale, however I can't find a way to get the locale format (as above).

Comment: You asked the exact same question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802765/finding-locale-date-representation-in-php5

This should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: wasn't sure how to 'claim a question'. close the other one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the problem?

```
date('m/d/Y')
```

or

```
date('d-m-Y')
```

Comment: I mean, I need to get the string in the middle there, the 'DD-MM-YYYY' or 'DD/MM/YYYY' etc.

Comment: Oh, ok, I understand what you want. But still I don't get why? Why don't you pass 'DD-MM-YYYY' and format the date that way?

Comment: Yea, i decided to do that in the end. Thanks for your help.